# Angular guard for checking if route has state

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-guards

I have a component to which navigate like this

```
this.router.navigate(['results'], { state });
```

and once there i grab the data in the contructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) { 
  const { state } = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras;
}
```

i want to place a guard to check for the existense of this data, otherwise navigate elsewhere

```
@Injectable()
export default class RouteHasDataGuard implements CanActivate { 
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!state.root.data;
    } 
}
```

but this isnt working. can you help me with this?

Comment: Angular route objects an inconsistently nested. You might want to put some breakpoints on your `return !!state.root.data` to figure out when it gets hit and if you're looking in the right object for your `state` data.

Comment: Have you tried with single ! ?

Comment: any data properties i find within route and state are empty as the transition happens, however the data is there when routing ends. what is single?

Answer (score 5):

Do not read extras in guard constructor. Read extras in canActivate() method.

```
@Injectable()
export default class RouteHasDataGuard implements CanActivate { 

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const { state } = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras;
    return !!state.root.data;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the status like this:

```
@Injectable()
export default class RouteHasDataGuard implements CanActivate { 
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!window.history.state;
    } 
}
```